# Running APC with suEXEC

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, suexec

Our servers are currently setup to run PHP as DSO with suEXEC enabled. Is it possible for us to install APC in this setup?

Servers are CentOS 5.2 running with WHM/cPanel

Comment: I would have thought this would present no issues - what went wrong when you tried it?

Comment: i was incorrectly told this wouldnt work - but it does. sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/entry.php?2234-Installing-APC-on-CentOS-5-Server

try out above link

:)

Answer (score 0):

You can install it, but you won't benefit much from it (depends on why you need APC though). When using suEXEC, every request for a dynamic page spawns a new process (which has a new, separate instance of APC). APC does not support shared memory, yet.